# xml handling in spring framework

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm receiving a xml by post request and I'm responding other xml for this petition by response. Now I'm implementing controller ModelandView to do it but I don't know if this implementation,  is the most easy or the best.

it may be  best to  implement,  a simple http servlet and not use spring  MVC?

What are you suggest for this implementation?

Thank you very much and sorry for my English
Best regards

Comment: I don´t think that a servlet is appropiate for you if you want to use Spring. What kind of POST request are you receiving? Is it a REST call? A SOAP call? In that cases you have better ways to handle it with Spring.

Comment: Thank. I'm receiving a normal xml from other application and I response other normal xml. No SOAP. I'm using apache http server and tomcat. Now I'm using servlet for receiving xml, but I thought upgrade my program for new technology. I saw spring framework and I thought programing with this framework for my code it will be more standard. Is there anybody  to give me any sample for I can start ?

Comment: Check out this Spring tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: Added my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion of implementation:
- Check out this Spring tutorial: [https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/]